# how to enable/disable drop down list after selecting radio button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, material-design

JSON Data:

```
radio1Data: any[] = [
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: 'Col-1' },
    { value: 'col-2', viewValue: 'Col-2' }

  ];
  radio2Data: any[] = [
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: 'Col-1' },
    { value: 'col-2', viewValue: 'Col-2' }

  ];
  radio2Value: any[] = [
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: '(10)' },
    { value: 'col-2', viewValue: '(4)' },
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: 'Custom' }
  ];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="window-pad-height">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <mat-radio-group>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">radio1
        </mat-radio-button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Select ">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let radio1 of radio1Data" [value]="radio1.value">
              {{radio1.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-radio-button value="2">radio2
        </mat-radio-button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Select ">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let radio2 of radio2Data" [value]="radio2.value">
              {{radio2.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="value">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let value of radio2value" [value]="radio2value.value">
              {{radio2value.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

when I select radio button 1 then radio 1 drop down must be getting enable and when I select radio button 2 then radio 2 drops down must get enable 
and when I select radio2Data then radio2value must get enable  and in drop-down list there is custom input if I select custom then custom input should be entered by end user!
how to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it with javascript.

Comment: No i have to work with type script

Comment: @ShreeBatale have pasted an answer with StackBlitz Example with Sample demo data, Check out!

Comment: @ShreeBatale Have a look at updated stackblitz i have implemented with your code! Check out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-km7xbu

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Thanks but your code is working opposite, could you please make changes as well!

Comment: @ShreeBatale done, Check once!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Thank you Sir ! Its working fine now :)

Comment: @ShreeBatale Great, Happy Coding!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Suppose i have three option in my drop down ONE, TWO, CUSTOM , when i select custom option then input box get enable until and unless selecting custom input box should be disabled! ? HOW TO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `[disabled]` attribute on the select controls which takes a boolean value.

Change this according to your radio button selected value.

Comment: could you please post stackblitz demo here it would be help full for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `disabled` attribute of Material Select to disable the Select option:

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-km7xbu)

Changes in your HTML Code:

```
<div class="window-pad-height">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <mat-radio-group>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <mat-radio-button value="1" (click)="onClick(1)">radio1</mat-radio-button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select placeholder="Select " [disabled]="isDisabled">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let radio1 of radio1Data" [value]="radio1.value">
                            {{radio1.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <mat-radio-button value="2" (click)="onClick(2)">radio2</mat-radio-button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select placeholder="Select " [disabled]="isDisabled1">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let radio2 of radio2Data" [value]="radio2.value">
                            {{radio2.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

        </div>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

In TS:

```
isDisabled: boolean = false;
isDisabled1: boolean = false;
onClick(rbNo) {
   f (rbNo == 1) {
      this.isDisabled = false;
      this.isDisabled1 = true;
   }
   else {
      this.isDisabled = true;
      this.isDisabled1 = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pimple Thank you Sir! your code is working opposite . when i select radi1 then radio2 drop down will get disabled

Comment: @PrashantPimple Hi, How to set default radio1 as selected!

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="selected"`

Comment: @PrashantPimple Thanks im trying but its not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    <label>{{season}}<input [disabled]="season !== favoriteSeason"></label>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

You can use ngmodel on the radio group. Then you give ecery button a [value] wich later gets assigned to your ngmodel variable. With [disabled] you can disable your mat selects (e.g. here my input).

In short you press a button. value is now the selected ngmodel(favorite season here). Now value === favorite season wich means disabled is now false

Comment: could you please posy stackblitz demo here! it would be help full for me as I'm beginner!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9re46d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts the material is kinda off but you get the idea